# sequences/limits

Tags: limits

The book I use is Jon Rogawski, multivariable calculus, chapter 1, question 39:
evaluate lim {n (sin 1/n)}, for n→∞.

the student solution manual gives a fairly detailed explanation, it says:
1):  lim (sinx)/x for x towards 0 = 1 (I understand that)
2):  this implies lim (sin1/x)/(1/x) for x→∞, I do not understand this implication.

Also, when I try to graph this, it most certainly looks like a divergent function, so how could there possibly be a limit? I know that the value of sin 1/n only oscillates between -1 and +1, but the factor n keeps increasing.

Thanks for helping,

Roswitha

Comment: In the second limit, $x$ is getting very large, so $1/x$ is approaching $0$. If it will help, let $t=1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put $y=1/x$. As $x \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow 0$. So,

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\sin(1/x)/(1/x)}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\sin(y)/y$

Answer (score 0):

Recalling Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ we have

> $$ n\sin(1/n) = n\left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3!n^3}+\dots \right) .$$

**Note:** for large $n$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\sim 0$.

Comment: I usually do not like this argument, as even though individual terms in a series go to zero, the series itself might not be zero- there are no issues here, due to various reasons- but it might not be a good idea to tell a beginning calculus student about this, as it sometimes leads to wrong math. Sorry- this is my personal opinion :).

Comment: @voldemort: It is a well known technique!

Comment: As I said- no issues here, but it's a matter of personal taste.. I generally advice caution; note that the caution is not for you- but for the beginning student. I am sure you know why this works- but sometimes students get into pitfalls while interchanging sums and limits.